# Converting a hex string to just hex in python

Tags: python-2.7, hex, ipv4

I have a program that takes an IPv4 address and converts it to hex. However, I am using a library that requires a variable using hex to be declared like this:

```
hexValue = 0x73FF0861
```

The method that I am using to convert the address to hex outputs a string, so whenever I assign the string hex value to a variable from the library, a value error is returned because the hex is a string. Is there any way in Python 2.7 to convert the IPv4 addresses to hex in a way that the library can use them?

Comment: Do you want to pass string `73FF0861` as hex number `0x73XX0861` (which is int 1946093665)?

Comment: Can you give the name of the library you are using which requires you to declare a hex value as you described above ?

Comment: @Alex.S yes, that is exactly what I would like to do.

Comment: Try to pass just the number 1946093665.

Comment: @Alex.S the class is still a string

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the hex string to hex as below:

```
ip_hex = hex(int('0x73FF0861', 16))
```

Comment: `type(ip_hex)` returns `<type 'str'>`

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Anyways, I am not sure how to represent a hex value without the quotes because declaring hexValue = 73FF0861 results in error

Comment: @Tejaswi sorry, I made a mistake. In the program, some variables are assigned with hexadecimal integers like 0x73FF0861, not the way that I originally described in my answer.

Comment: @ Broad: ok. No problem. Can you please undo the "-1" ?